# ReactJS Promise resolve() doesn't pass the value to .then() but reject() pass the value to .catch()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-cognito

I am trying to make a project with ReactJS and AWS Cognito. I am using all auth functions in auth.js folder. In login screen, I am trying to get the session information from auth.js like this:

auth.js

```
var getSessionInfo = async () => {
        await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const user = Pool.getCurrentUser();
            if (user) {
                user.getSession((err, session) => {
                    if(err){
                        reject(err)
                    }else{
                        resolve(session)
                    }
                })
            } else {
                reject()
            }
        })
    }
```

and in login.js

```
getSessionInfo()
      .then(session => {
        console.log("session:", session)
        setIsAuth(true)

        if (isAuth) {
          history.push("/home")
        }
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log("err:", err)
      })
```

In login.js, `.then(session => {...})` this session is always undefined. None of the resolves returns the values, no matter what I write in it.

But the fun part is if I use `reject()` instead of `resolve()` and use `.catch()` instead of `.then()` the values passes perfectly. If I can't find the cause of it I might use Promises this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The promise await is **not being returned**.
- Therefore, even though the value is resolved, it's not being returned to the callback.
- Add **return** here:

```
return await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
```

Answer (score 1):

The `getSessionInfo` forgets to return anything from the function, so the returned value is always `undefined`. You also don't have to `await` the promise as you are not using the result of the promise later on in the function.

Instantly return the promise and lose the `async / await` (which would make sense when you call the `getSessionInfo` function) to solve your issue.

```
const getSessionInfo = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const user = Pool.getCurrentUser();
  if (user) {
    user.getSession((err, session) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(err)
      }
      resolve(session);
    });
  }
  reject();
});
```

Down here `async / await` would make sense as you want to actually wait for the value from `getSessionInfo` before continuing.

```
(async () => {
  try {
    const session = await getSessionInfo();
    console.log("session:", session)
    setIsAuth(true)
    if (isAuth) {
      history.push("/home")
    }
  } catch(error) {
    console.log("err:", err)
  }
})()
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I will refactor my code and try yours

Comment: It seems without `return` in front of `new Promise(())` it never pass the value from `resolve(value)`

Comment: An arrow function  without curly braces `{ }` implicitly returns the promise. `() => new Promise()` is the same as `() => { return new Promise(); }`

Comment: Okay Thanks! It seems i couldn't grasp many feature of JS.